# replace all language spaces with standardized space

Tags: php

Am working on a simple search input. It splits terms by space, which works nicely. However it does not recognize other languages spaces.

I'd like to preg_replace other languages spaces to a standardized space.

example,

```
$pattern       = array(
   //insert other language space codes here (I don't know what they are or how to find them) 
);
$replacement   = ' ';
$string        = "日本語　の　スペース　です";

$cleaned = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);
```

Comment: Did you try `preg_replace('/\s/', ' ', $string)`? Maybe Regex will catch other language spaces

Comment: @sjagr unfortunately it didn't catch it. It will catch the space if I type in the specific space. Which I will probably do in the meantime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `u` modifier in your pattern along with the `\s` escape sequence which will match *any* space character.  This would look something like this (using your code):

```
$pattern   = '/\s/u';
$replacement = '';
$string        = "日本語　の　スペース　です";

$cleaned = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string);

var_dump($cleaned);
```

Output:

```
string(30) "日本語のスペースです"
```

From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/reference.pcre.pattern.modifiers.php):

> u (PCRE_UTF8)
>
> This modifier turns on additional functionality of PCRE that is incompatible with Perl. Pattern and subject strings are treated as UTF-8. This modifier is available from PHP 4.1.0 or greater on Unix and from PHP 4.2.3 on win32. UTF-8 validity of the pattern and the subject is checked since PHP 4.3.5. An invalid subject will cause the preg_* function to match nothing; an invalid pattern will trigger an error of level E_WARNING. Five and six octet UTF-8 sequences are regarded as invalid since PHP 5.3.4 (resp. PCRE 7.3 2007-08-28); formerly those have been regarded as valid UTF-8.